# Create a folder in a privileged place

Tags: java

I need to make a folder that is in the users home directory on  mac in Java. When I run the code, it gives me a security exception. How can I authenticate? Here is the error:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
at goatSoftware.CreateJFrame$2$1.actionPerformed(CreateJFrame.java:95)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here is the current code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try{
                        if (OS.contains("OS X")){
                            File folder = new File("FarmCalc");
                            // if file doesn't exist, then create it
                            if (!folder.exists()){
                                folder.createNewFile();
                            }
                            final File file = new File("/Users/"+user+"/FarmCalc/"+beta.getText()+".txt");
                            // if file doesn't exist, then create it
                            if (!file.exists()) {
                                file.createNewFile();
                            }
                            FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                            String getInfo = beta.getText();
                            fileOut.write("name: "+getInfo);
                            fileOut.close();
                            newJFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(newJFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                            JFrame jf = new JFrame("Description for "+getInfo);
                            jf.setVisible(true);
                        } else {
                            final File file = new File("C:\\FarmCalc\\"+beta.getText()+".txt");
                            // if file doesn't exists, then create it
                            if (!file.exists()) {
                                file.createNewFile();
                            }
                            FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                            String getInfo = beta.getText();
                            fileOut.write("name: "+getInfo);
                            fileOut.close();
                            newJFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(newJFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

I don't see what went wrong.

Comment: Use [Paths.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) It's easy for basic implementations...

Comment: Pls don't down vote without an explanation

Comment: I didn't... wrong culprit mate ;) But if you want a reason ... read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Not you, just somebody else, because I just saw it go down.

Comment: look, now its down 4!!

Comment: I don't interpret `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory` as a security exception.

Comment: what about `at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)`

Comment: and `at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)`

Comment: The reason the folder can't be found is that it won't let me make it.

Comment: Notice how those calls are done within the awt framework, completely unrelated to your custom code.

Comment: oh, So what do I do then?

Comment: I don't think `createNewFile` creates any missing directories. So check if those exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a file then trying to treat it as a folder.

Your code

```
                        File folder = new File("FarmCalc");
                        // if file doesn't exist, then create it
                        if (!folder.exists()){
                            folder.createNewFile();
                        }
                        final File file = new File("/Users/"+user+"/FarmCalc/"+beta.getText()+".txt");
                        // if file doesn't exist, then create it
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
```

Should be

```
                        File folder = new File("FarmCalc");
                        // if file doesn't exist, then create it
                        if (!folder.exists()){
                            folder.mkdir();
                        }
                        final File file = new File("/Users/"+user+"/FarmCalc/"+beta.getText()+".txt");
                        // if file doesn't exist, then create it
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks!! Finally, someone who understands what I was saying!!

Comment: As the saying goes, it's difficult to separate the wheat from the chaff.  :)

Comment: Yeah, but they never say that its so hard.